# Programmatically controlling application servers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm creating an application that relies heavily on dynamic creation/management of various resources like jms queues, webservice endpoints, jdbc connections... I have a background in java EE and am currently working on a jboss 7 server however I'm finding it increasingly difficult to control these things programmatically. The hardest thing to control seem to be the webservices. I need to be able to generate WSDLs (and XSDs) on the fly, manage the endpoints, soap handlers etc and the system simply does not seem to be set up to do that.

Other application servers don't seem to really offer any groundbreaking solutions so I'm wondering whether perhaps java EE is not the best solution to this particular problem?

Is there an application server that allows you to do just that? Is there another technology that does? Should I just roll a custom solution that integrates all the separate modules (e.g. a jms server, a web server etc...)?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, most java EE stuff is accomplished through a mixture of annotations and XML configuration. This however assumes that you have a POJO and/or a jar/war/... per resource.

Suppose I have a @WebServiceProvider bean which can be reused for multiple input/output combinations (for example because it dynamically redirects the content). I need to be able to deploy a new "instance" of the provider on the fly. This means I do not want to duplicate the code and redeploy it, I just want to take that one existing bean on the classpath and deploy it multiple times with different configuration settings. This also means I need to manage the WSDL dynamically. The end result should be a webservice that works pretty much like a standard webservice on the application server with the necessary integrated security, soap handlers,...

I imagine that at some point in the application server code, there must be a class "WebserviceManager" which has a method like "createWebservice(...)" that is actually used by the deployment module whenever it discovers a webservice annotation. I want access to that method and similar methods for creating jdbc connections, jms queues,...

Comment: It would appear that you need to be looking towards deployment automation: puppet, chef, etc. On a smaller scale some of that can be achieved with maven.

Comment: Not really, the tool itself must manage all the different aspects, not rely on external tools and procedures to get something up and running.

Comment: Do you need to create this resources while the application is running or on deploy?

Comment: While the application is running.

Comment: You might have a look at glassfish and admin-cli.jar. I know you can add resources but don't know if you can add all and if they are available instantly.

Comment: There is something wrong in your question : you're asking for a tool to manage app server configuration, however the point you're talking about is not a part of the app server : a WSDL is generated from the Java code of an application. I would gladly suggest you evolve your question into "how to dynamically deploy web services in my JavaEE applications ?". On a side note, I strongly suggest you take a look at [what asadmin offers as commands](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/gentextid-110.html), you'll see there is no thing such as dynamic WSDL creation.

Comment: The lack of a dynamic WSDL is in the first place a problem on the JAX-WS side but one could imagine an implementation that does allow it. Ideally I would like to use the available infrastructure (all the handlers etc) but have more control over the endpoints/definitions. It's not only about webservices though, I need to manage dynamically, programmatically, certain aspects of the application server. Things that are normally done through annotations on POJO's should be accessible through an interface. Where @WebService generates a webservice, I would like a WebserviceManager.createWebservice().

Answer (score 1):

You can use OSGi for these kind of scenarios. It is perfect for hot deployment of varios modules.

Comment: OSGi assumes that I actually have a module. The point is to create and manage resources on the fly without the availability of an annotated POJO.

Comment: @user1109519 You can define a Resources API by yourself or use an existing API to do just that. Also don't forget that the annotated POJOs are just a shortcut, you can get more control if you directly use related OSGi service APIs.

Comment: So you can use a programmatic OSGi interface to register a webservice without creating dummy xmls, pojo's or any artifact? If so, could you point me to a tutorial? I've never seen OSGi used like this.

Comment: Well, I don't know if there is any tutorial for that, but OSGi is sure capable of doing that. For example, you can use the standard OSGi HttpService (http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/http/package-summary.html) for registering web services as they are available.

Cleanest solution would be to use a whiteboard approach for auto-loading web services.